# How to make glow effect in cocos2dx

Tags: cocos2d-x

i searching the web for glowing effect , i like to be able to create misc glowing effects ,
like lasers , glow around sprites and such .
couldn't find any thing on the web , any body have any direction ?
something like this :
[image]

Comment: This is usually achieved by blurring the lightmap in screen-space. Read about bloom shaders and give it a try.

Comment: This article is a bit old, but presents a possible technique: http://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/130520/realtime_glow.php